# Will JavaScript always be executed before the web page finishes loading if it is placed in the ```<head>```?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if the statement is **true** or **false** just to be sure. I answer similar question online with true, but the correct answer stated the statement is false.

Comment: Basically yes if it's inline, or without a `defer` and/or `async` attribute when loading the code from a js file

Comment: Javascript will always be executed as soon as it is loaded, often before the DOM is completely ready. This is why in a lot of cases, people add onReady listeners with either jQuery or event listeners for the DOMContentLoaded event